# My insert statement is not inserting any rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have two tables that look like this:

- `game` (id, title, location)
- `gamePlayers` (playerType, gameId)

I can see that I have 90 games that do not have a corresponding id in my `gamePlayers` table with this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.game
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT gameId FROM dbo.gamePlayers)
```

So I want to create entries for the missing games and add the value '1' for the `playerType`, and the id of the game for `gameId`.

So I tried this:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.gamePlayers
    SELECT 1, p.id 
    FROM dbo.game p
    WHERE p.id NOT IN (SELECT gameId FROM dbo.gamePlayers)
```

But it doesn't insert anything at all.

Shouldn't it insert 90 rows?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any NULL gameID values? `NOT IN` will never return true in that case. Check with `SELECT gameId FROM dbo.gamePlayers WHERE gameId IS NULL;`.

Comment: Is `gameId` `NULL`able, by any chance? If so, this is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/in-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#result-value) behaviour (see the big red box). Use a `NOT EXISTS` instead. To be honest, I often think using `(NOT) EXISTS` in the first place is often the better choice.

Comment: @DanGuzman No I just checked. There are no NULL gameID values in the gamePlayers table.

Comment: @Larnu I have gameId set to NOT NULL.  thank u

Comment: What does the `SELECT` in your `INSERT INTO` statement return, if you run it just by itself ? Does it in fact return 90 rows as you expect?

Comment: @marc_s it does return 90 rows if I just run it without the INSERT INTO part

Comment: You should specify the column list for your `INSERT` statement to make sure you're inserting into the correct columns.

Comment: Considerng that, apart from the columns in the `SELECT` and the preceding `INSERT INTO` clause, those statements are the same, this suggests what is in your question, and what you are doing are not equal. Time for a [mre] in my opinion.

Comment: Time for giving us the response that MS-SQL is giving you (I suspect something like "Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.")

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NOT IN vs NOT EXISTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173041/not-in-vs-not-exists)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does the following slight refactor work for you?

```
insert into dbo.gamePlayers(playerType, gameId)
select 1, p.id 
from dbo.game p
where not exists (select * from gamePlayers gp where gp.gameId=p.Id)
```